# Google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest can't recognize bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I follow community google cloud platform to connect to twilio to capture voice call and save to bucket.  However, it can't translate the voice, due to the following error message. Does anyone know why
`google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest` can't recognize bucket?

(url: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-twilio-voice-record)

> "Error: .google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest#bucket is not a field: undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at MessagePrototype.set (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2490:35)
>       at MessagePrototype.set (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2483:38)
>       at Message (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2411:34)
>       at serialize (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/protobuf_js_5_common.js:81:23)
>       at ServiceClient.Client.makeUnaryRequest (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:530:17)
>       at apply (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:499:17)
>       at ServiceClient.wrapper [as recognize] (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:5356:16)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/src/v1/speech_client.js:111:41
>       at timeoutFunc (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/speech/node_modules/google-gax/lib/api_callable.js:177:12)"
>    timestamp:  "2017-08-07T17:27:02.601Z"

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with the following code:

```
var config = {
  sampleRateHertz: 8000,
  encoding: 'LINEAR16',
  languageCode: 'en-US'


};
var uri = `gs://${object.bucket}/${object.name}`;
var audio = {
  uri : uri
 };
var request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio
};

// Transcribe the audio file
return speech.recognize(request)
```

By the way: I also had to comment out the 'annotate' function below to get it to work

Comment: I'm running into the same issue... Could you post your full file on a gist or something?  And if you comment out the annotate function, doesn't that mean you're not doing any analyzing?

Comment: I don't have a complete solution. I used this example to create something for my own use case.